# Insert distinct records to table in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I want to insert records from first table to second in such a way that only unique records get inserted. That is if table one and two has overlapping (duplicate) records, only the unique records get inserted into table one from table two. For example I have one table named Table_One,

[image]

and another table named Table_Two,

[image]

now I want to add the records from Table_Two the records that are not already in Table_one which is (XYZ | UVW) so that the output is,

[image]

I tried using this technique,

```
INSERT INTO TableB(Col1, Col2, Col3, ... , Coln)
SELECT DISTINCT A.Col1, A.Col2, A.Col3, ... , A.Coln
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B
ON A.KeyOfTableA = B.KeyOfTableB
WHERE B.KeyOfTableB IS NULL
```

but the duplicate rows also got inserted, any suggestions as to what could be the solution ??? I am using sqlite3 db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    INSERT INTO TableB (Col1, Col2, Col3, ... , Coln)
SELECT DISTINCT A.Col1, 
                A.Col2, 
                A.Col3, 
                ... , 
                A.Coln
           FROM TableA A
          WHERE A.KeyOfTableA NOT IN (SELECT B.KeyOfTableB
                                           FROM TableB B)
```

Comment: yah, i also observed from tutorial that it "IS" too much. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `UNION`.

**Query**

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE table1(firstName VARCHAR(50),lastName VARCHAR(50));
sqlite> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('ABC','DEF');
sqlite> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('GHI','JKL');
sqlite> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('MNO','PQR');
sqlite>
sqlite> CREATE TABLE table2(first VARCHAR(50),last VARCHAR(50));
sqlite> INSERT INTO table2 VALUES('ABC','DEF');
sqlite> INSERT INTO table2 VALUES('XYZ','UVW');
sqlite> .headers ON
sqlite> SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROm table2;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
firstName|lastName
ABC|DEF
GHI|JKL
MNO|PQR
XYZ|UVW
```

Comment: thank you for this new perspective, but I want to permenently insert into the table. Kindly suggest how I might be able to save XYZ | UVW, cuz your present answer only gives me an option to view the distinct records, but these viewed records are not getting saved anywhere in table.